# rails 3 paperclip processor watermark error in filename

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a problem with paperclip in rails 3. When I upload a file my processor throws error because imagemagick get command:

"composite -gravity South /home/xxx/xxx/public/images/watermark.png /tmp/a s20121207-5819-1dq7y81.jpg /tmp/a s20121207-5819-1dq7y8120121207-5819-1juqw7a"

composite: unable to open image `/tmp/a':

processor:

```
def make
  dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
  dst.binmode

  if @watermark_path
    command = "composite"
    params = "-gravity #{@position} #{@watermark_path} #{fromfile} "
    params += tofile(dst)
    begin
      p " >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> #{command} #{params}"
      success = Paperclip.run(command, params)
    rescue PaperclipCommandLineError
      success = false
    end
    unless success
      raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
    end
    return dst
  else
    return @file
  end
end

def fromfile
  File.expand_path(@file.path)
end

def tofile(destination)
  File.expand_path(destination.path)
end
```

it only occurs when filename have whitespace or other non alfanum chars. The /tmp/a should be /tmp/a b.jpg.

I'va tried http://www.davesouth.org/stories/make-url-friendly-filenames-in-paperclip-attachments and more but still filename in processor is wrong

any ideas? or processor that works ok for this issue? :(

Comment: you should remove white spaces from filenames...

Comment: I have done this but it doesn't work I think that paperclip creates tmp files before removing spaces

Comment: but you create tempfile by yourown??
dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))

Comment: no, this file in pass in constructor:  def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super

Comment: Any luck with this problem? I am having exactly the same problem. I was looking around the source but I just couldn't find out how to possibly remove illegal characters from @file.path. I settle down by just having a validate_format_of on photo_file_name which is not really a direct solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it maybe with:

```
dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join(".").gsub(" ","")
```

Comment: thx but the wrong filename is also in @file which is pass in procesor initializer, I dont know where I could change this "file" before create watermark instance

Answer (score 0):

I came back to this today and figured out you just need to enclose the path with a quote as in the ImageMagic documentation (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php):

```
If the image path includes one or more spaces, enclose the path in quotes:

'my title.jpg'
```

As an example, in my processor I have:

```
command = "convert \"#{File.expand_path(@file.path)}\" -crop #{crop_area} -resize 150x150 \"#{File.expand_path(destination.path)}\""

Paperclip.run(command)
```

.

I am on Windows at the moment and single quote doesn't seem to work.
Like you, I tried changing attributes of @file with no success.

Hope it helps.